# Delete all paragraphs that begin with time (HH:mm) and end with specific string from multiple files

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, sed

I need to delete any paragraphs/blocks of text that begin with a time in HH:mm format and end with a specific string from a large number of files in a folder. Each paragraph that needs deleting ends with the string #file. Between each paragraph is a blank line. Is it possible to delete everything between these two? Sample file as follows:

```
00:00  
-Paragraph one. Can be multiple  
lines. Paragraph one. Don't delete  
this paragraph. #No

19:30  
-Paragraph two.  
-Can be multiple lines.  
-Delete this paragraph. #file

13.30  
-Paragraph three. Delete this. #file
```

---

So ideally what would be left is:

```
00:00  
-Paragraph one. Can be multiple  
lines. Paragraph one. Don't delete  
this paragraph. #No
```

The paragraphs won't ever be the first paragraph of the document, but they could be the last.

I'm no expert so I've been trying things I found online with no luck. Thanks for any help you can give me!

--

Edit:

Thanks everyone for all the help. I ended up with this as it was closer to what I tried already, worked perfectly for anyone looking for something similar:

gawk -i inplace 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n"}!/#file/' *.md

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
00:00
-Paragraph one. Can be multiple
lines. Paragraph one. Don't delete
this paragraph. #No

19:30
-Paragraph two.
-Can be multiple lines.
-Delete this paragraph. #file

13.30
-Paragraph three. Delete this. #file
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}!/#file/' file.txt
```

gives output

```
00:00
-Paragraph one. Can be multiple
lines. Paragraph one. Don't delete
this paragraph. #No
```

Explanation: I set `RS` (row separator) to empty string which triggers paragraph mode, so rows are separatored by one or more blank lines, then I select rows which do not (`!`) contains `#file`. If there is more than one item to keep there will be no blank line between them, if this is desired replace `RS=""` using `RS=ORS="\n\n"`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/#file$/' file
00:00
-Paragraph one. Can be multiple
lines. Paragraph one. Don't delete
this paragraph. #No
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in Perl. As you haven't shown us what you've tried, I'm not going to explain how it works. But it's written as a [Unix filter](https://dev.to/davorg/the-unix-filter-model-what-why-and-how-fi).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $buffer;

while (<>) {
  if (/^\d\d:\d\d\s*$/) {
    end_of_para($buffer);

    $buffer = $_;
  } else {
    $buffer .= $_
  }
}

end_of_para($buffer);

sub end_of_para {
  my ($para) = @_;

  if ($para and $para !~ /#file\s*\z/) {
    print $para;
  }
}
```

**Update:** You've changed the sample input file. That makes things far simpler.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = '';

while (<>) {
  print unless /#file\s*\z/;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative. Not 100% clear what the requirements for the first paragraph are, so I've printed it unconditionally.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

# set paragraph mode
local $/ = "";

# always print first paragraph
print scalar <DATA> ;

while (<DATA>)
{
    print 
        unless /^\d\d:\d\d.*#file\s*$/s;
}

__DATA__
01:01
keep this text even though it has #file

another paragraph with no data

01:00
delete this #file

07:057
delete this as well #file

keep this paragraph

02:33
keep me
```

running produces this output

```
01:01
keep this text even though it has #file

another paragraph with no data

keep this

02:33
keep me
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/{:a;$!{N;/\n$/!ba};/#file\n?$/!p}' file
```

Turn on extended regexp's and off implicit printing.

Gather up lines starting with `HH:MM` and ending in a blank line or end of file. If the last string is not `#file` print the result.

Repeat.